# Passing additional parameters apart from parameter file in arm template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have some arm template where creation of subnet resource is dependent on creation of VNet. Below is the code:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Virtual Network"
      }
    },
    "vnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP Address pool for the virtual network in CIDR format."
      }
    },
    "subnetPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The IP Address pool for the Subnet in CIDR format."
      }
    },
    "subnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Name of the Subnet"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "templateBaseUrl": "[deployment().properties.templateLink.uri]",
    "virtualNetworkTemplateUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'VirtualNetwork.json')]",
    "subnetTemplateUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'Subnet.json')]",
    "parametersUrl": "[uri(variables('templateBaseUrl'), 'networksubnetnsgtest.parameters.json')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "VnetDeployment",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('virtualNetworkTemplateUrl')]"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2017-05-10",
      "name": "SubnetDeployment",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[variables('subnetTemplateUrl')]"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "VnetDeployment"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "returnedVnetName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetName'))]"
    },
    "returnedVnetAddressPrefix": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('vnetAddressPrefix'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Few parameters are saved in parameter file referred by parameterUrl variable, as you can see. But apart from this, i need to pass additional parameters say like password or any required parameter , which i may be reading from external sources like vault, and need to pass from commandline.
How will i pass this in **parameters** section within resources.

Command i am using to deploy azure template is below:

```
az group deployment create --resource-group testrg --template-file ${WORKSPACE}/azuredeploy.json --parameters @${WORKSPACE}/networksubnetnsgtest.parameters.json --parameters DBMasterUserPassword=${DBMasterUserPassword}
```

Comment: Hi, just want to check whether 4c74356b41's last suggestion is useful for you? If not, feel free to leave comment below. Then we could continue to help for solving this issue.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I am still in doubt. In above json , i have 2 resources, 1 VNetDeployment and 2) SubnetDeployment. Now SubNetDeployment requires 2 type of parameters. 1) Mentioned in networksubnetnsgtest.parameters.json file which i am passing as "uri": {  "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]" }  2) On some password, which i am passing as --parameter <credentialname>=<credentialvalue> during CLI command execution. Now how will i pass <credentialname>=<credentialvalue> as parameter to SubnetDeployment resource in parameter {} section. Or i need not to pass in parameter {} section.

Answer (score 1):

excerpt from official documentation:

```
az group deployment create -g MyResourceGroup --template-file azuredeploy.json \
    --parameters @params.json --parameters https://mysite/params.json --parameters MyValue=This MyArray=@array.json
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest#examples

Comment: so , suppose in above example i have deployment resource SubnetDeployment, which deploys subnet resource using Subnet.json and inside the Subnet.json, i am using parameter MyValue i.e. "parameters('MyValue')" , so will it get the parameter value by own or we need to pass parameter value in parameters section in azuredeploy.json apart from parameter file reference            "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking, but you cannot pass parameters to nested template (parent template will do that) you can only pass parameters to the parent

Comment: so how the parameter value will propogate to nested template, if it is being used in nested template. say keeping secrets in parameter file is not possible, then how to pass secrets parameter to nested template apart from nested template parameter file?.

Comment: you will pass it in the template, like you are supposed to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates#inline-parameters

Comment: correct, in above provided link by you, we pass parameters as        
       "parameters": {
          "StorageAccountName":{"value": "[parameters('StorageAccountName')]"}
        }  but now how will i pass parameter file url  like we are passing above "parameters": {
          "uri": {
            "value": "[variables('parametersUrl')]"
          }
        }. Is it possible to pass both url and say storageaccount name as parameters?

Comment: no, they are mutually exclusive, if you mean that you want to pass parameters as a link you can only do that, that page has examples of that as well

Comment: but now how can i pass additional parameters. Do i have some way, like i cant put secrets in parameter.json, that i need to pass via vault or oter sources, which i am passing while executing the resource deployment command. So how can it be possible along with parameter.json file to nested template

Comment: you cant use parameters file link and parameters, so you have to use parameters and can link them from key vault as well. basically like [so](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/parent.json#L151).